# NuGet: Don't include reference from package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

**Summary**

When I package a library using NuGet and reference it in another project the referring project will pull additonal files in to the build directory.

**Working Case**

```
Project: ReferenceLibrary
  Output: ReferenceLibrary.dll

Project: DerivedLibrary
  Output: DerivedLibrary.dll
  References: ReferenceLibrary (Copy Local = False)

Project: ConsoleApplication
  Output: ConsoleApplication.exe
  References: DerivedLibrary
```

Edit: The reference library is not copied because it is resolved at runtime.  There's several versions depending on the target.  The reference in derive proj. is so I can code against it.

If I build this then only DerivedLibrary.dll is copied to the ConsoleApplication build folder (i.e. bin/Release).

**Non-working Case**

```
Project: ConsoleApplication
  Output: ConsoleApplication.exe
  Package: DerivedLibrary.nupkg (depends on ReferenceLibrary.nupkg)
```

A project reference is added to DerivedLibray.dll.  Both DerivedLibrary.dll and the ReferenceLibrary.dll are copied from their packages.

I can see it being copied in the MSBUILD log.

```
_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
    Copying file from "c:\...\ReferenceLibrary.dll" to "bin\Debug\ReferenceLibrary.dll"
```

Even though it's not referenced in the .csproj anywhere.

I can't tell if this is a NuGet problem (due to how it unpacks things) or a Visual Studio project (how it copies referenced assemblies and encodes the requirements in other assemblies).

Comment: If Derived library depends on Reference library, are you really surprised that the application using Derived library also needs Reference library to function? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to remove this complexity as the question becomes really unwiedly.  The reference library is resolved at runtime (hence I don't want it copied to the output folder).  I'll add it back in.

Comment: If it's referenced at runtime, is your application only going to run if someone manually drops it into the `bin` folder or into the GAC? What's the use case for this?

Comment: The ReferenceLibrary contains several versions of the same dll targetting different platforms (x86/x64 etc).  These are packaged in a .nupkg as content.  An assembly resolver class chooses the correct content directory (e.g. bin/Release/SomeVendor/64bit/ReferenceLibrary.dll) one and loads it from the content directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution I've found is to use a post build target to delete the offending references.

In the derived library add a DerivedLibrary.targets file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="RemoveUnwantedReferences" AfterTargets="Build">
      <Message Text="Removing unwanted references"/>
      <Delete Files="$(OutputPath)ReferenceLibrary.dll"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Then in the .nuspec include it

```
<package>
  ...
  <files>
    <file src="Targets/DerivedLibrary.targets" target="/build/DerivedLibrary.targets" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Then when someone installs the package the post build hook will be added.  When they build the files that are copied will then be deleted automatically.